# Weird result when copying integer to char * in c

Tags: c, arrays, char, integer

I am trying to copy an integer value to a char * but I always get a weird result on integers above 127.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Running test\n");

    char x[2];
    int y = 127, z = 128;
    printf("\ny: "); fflush(stdout);
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        printf("%d", (y >> i) & 0x1);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("\nz: "); fflush(stdout);
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        printf("%d", (z >> i) & 0x1);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    *x = y;
    printf("\nxy: "); fflush(stdout);
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        printf("%d", (*x >> i) & 0x1);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("\nxz: "); fflush(stdout);
    *x = z;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        printf("%d", (*x >> i) & 0x1);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

---

Running test

y: 11111110000000000000000000000000
z: 00000001000000000000000000000000
xy: 11111110000000000000000000000000
xz: 00000001111111111111111111111111

---

For compilation I use gcc v 5.4.0 (with just the output flag if that matters):
"gcc test.c -o test"

Any help is appreciated

Comment: dont `fflush(stdout)`just use `\n`in `printf` when your line is finished otherwise wait until it is finished.... In the rare cases that you really need to see it there without newline you can flush. But the way you use it it just clutters the code...

Comment: @KamiKaze - What if you don't want to line break at the particular spot?

Comment: I need to fflush to have the bit values all printed out nice and clean in a line .. so that the result is readable

Comment: @StoryTeller was in the progress of editing my comment, to reflect that

Comment: If you have a `signed char` that can typically represent numbers in the range -128 to +127. Also right-shifting a negative signed value is *implementation defined*.

Comment: @Miistogun you dont have to use fflush anywhere in your code just put a printf("\n") after your loop. http://ideone.com/zQ2DmA

Comment: It works with a unsigned char Thanks @Weather Vane for the solution .. maybe you can post it so i can close the thread

Comment: There's too much wrong here. Number one is to stop using `char` for storing numbers, because it is inherently shitty and non-portable for such purposes. Number two is to ensure that there are no signed integers anywhere in you bitwise arithmetic, instead of _only_ signed integers like you have now - there's poorly-defined behavior all over the place. Number three is to stop using the native primitive data types of C and use stdint.h instead. When you got rid of all the bugs caused by the above, you can focus on things like byte endianess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `signed char` it can typically represent numbers in the range -128 to +127. Most compilers by default use a `char` that is signed.

So even without shifting, numbers above 127 will not be represented correctly.

Also right-shifting a negative signed value is *implementation defined*.

Comment: Typically. Most. Well, "most" ARM compilers use `unsigned` by default. Should we rely on uncertainties?

Comment: @Kamiccolo if that had been the case, the question would not have asked. I could have added that many embedded compilers use `unsigned char` by default, but OP simply asked me to post the comment that gave him the solution, not a definitive answer to every situation. Perhaps you did not read the comments.

Comment: @Kamiccolo `unsigned` is equivalent to `unsigned int`. Did you mean `unsigned char`?